# Details of Nebula Nattable filtering

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, nattable

It looks as though implementing filter function in Nebula Nattable is difficult.
Even the example given is hard to understand. would someone point to an explanation on the various classes used in implementing the filter function ?

Comment: You need to be more precise in what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to add static filtering or do you want to use the filter row for dynamic filtering?

Comment: Sorry if I am too basic in my questioning. what is the difference between the two ? I am actually looking at the `FilterRowExampleGridLayer` class which provides the layers for the Dynamic filtering example. would be helpful if the class `FilterRowExampleGridLayer` is explained in detail.

Comment: Static filtering basically means to filter programmatically while the filter row allows a user to filter manually at runtime. I'm not sure what you expect. I can write a whole chapter about the details, but that takes too much time for doing it in short. The only thing that should be of interest atm should be the glazedlists FilterList and the filter row layer that is part of the column header. Maybe one of the German articles and examples (documented in English) linked at the NatTable documentation are helpful http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=articles

Comment: Thanks Dirk for taking time to answer. In the FilterRowExampleGridLayer class , the dataprovider is created in multiple steps. ie., an EventList object is created , then a  FilterList object is created and finally dataprovider. This is where I felt lost and think that there is no enough documentation. Also setting data seems to be of multiple steps rather than a traditional SWT TableViewer. Could this be simplified in future releases?

Comment: Regarding the list usage, this is because of GlazedLists http://www.glazedlists.com and setting data is different but really not complicated. You have a list of objects and need to provide access to the fields. Have a look at my getting started tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html I don't think there is much to simplify and we haven't planned something for that point

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I will try out the filter example

Answer (score 0):

Override applyFilter() method in DefaultGlazedListsFilterStrategy

Comment: NatTable is completely configurable, there is no need to override methods in the default implementations.